# How would i connect these two columns as one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, db2

I want to find the count of repeated names in a table of name list. 
it's like

```
names       
------
jhon
jhon
jack
jhon
jack
```

I did the following query to count the occurrences of the names

```
select count(names) as namejhon from table_team where names=‘jhon’  
select count(names) as namejack from table_team where names=‘jack’
```

**from this, I want to get the following table**(desired result)

```
namejhon       namejack
----------- -----------
         3          2

  1 record(s) selected.
```

**but when using  *JOIN* am getting  this**

```
namejack       
----------- 
         5        

  1 record(s) selected.
```

what can I do to get the desired result? any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will give you the information you want, but it is a query, not a table. If you truly want to create a table in which the column/field names are the peoples' names and the rows/records are just the counts, you should look at the CREATE TABLE documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-tables.html and the INSERT command documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(names) AS COUNT,
    names
FROM
    table_team
WHERE
    names in ('jhon', 'jack')
GROUP BY
    names
```

ADDED AFTER NEW INFO FROM ORIGINAL POSTER:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS nameJack FROM table_team WHERE `names` = 'jack') AS SUB1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS nameJhon FROM table_team WHERE `names` = 'jhon') AS SUB2
    ON
    (
    SUB1.`nameJack` <> SUB2.`nameJhon`
    OR
    SUB1.`nameJack` = SUB2.`nameJhon`
     )
```

Comment: yeah, I mean query and the code you provided doesn't do it. I mean like the desired query that am looking for. because I need to make the names1 and name2 the columns and you made them rows

Comment: Then what you need is to create a table with columns named nameJack and name Jhon. Then you need to insert the query results into the table.

Comment: is there a way to do it without creating a table and that's why am here or asking here but thanks!!

Comment: There is no way to use a table that has not been created because tables don't exist until they have been created.

Comment: not trying to make a table just trying to find a way to combine this two selects together select count(names) as namejhon from table_team where names=‘jhon’  
select count(names) as namejack from table_team where names=‘jack’

Comment: okay, I think I'm clear on what you want now and I edited my answer accordingly. If that's what you want, please mark as answered. Otherwise, please clarify.

Comment: pasted the wrong version last time, just corrected.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

Use two subselects.

```
SELECT (SELECT count(names)
               FROM table_team
               WHERE names = 'jhon') namejhon,
       (SELECT count(names)
               FROM table_team
               WHERE names = 'jack') namejack;
```

If you want to materialise that, use the `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` snytax.

```
CREATE TABLE jhon_and_jack
AS
SELECT (SELECT count(names)
               FROM table_team
               WHERE names = 'jhon') namejhon,
       (SELECT count(names)
               FROM table_team
               WHERE names = 'jack') namejack;
```

I don't know about DB2 though. But that should also give you pointers for that.